# Using \b in a regex, trying not to match words that start with $

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble getting the desired output using negative lookahead.

```
import re
text = "$FOO FOO $BAR BAR"

# Expected. Return words without 'F'.
re.findall(r"\b(?!F)\w+", text)
> ['BAR', 'BAR']

# Expected. Return words without 'B'.
re.findall(r"\b(?!B)\w+", text)
> ['FOO', 'FOO']

# Unexpected. Return words without '$'.
re.findall(r"\b(?!\$)\w+", text)
> ['FOO', 'FOO', 'BAR', 'BAR']
```

The first two work as expected. I expect the last one to return the list `['FOO', 'BAR']` matching words without the "$" character. Because it's a special character, I've tried various ways to escape it but haven't found the right solution.

Comment: `(?!F)\w+` isn't checking that the whole word has no F, only that the first character of it isn't an F

Comment: The problem you have here is that `\b` matches at any word separator, and `$foo` isn't considered a single word -- it has a word boundary between the `$` and the `foo` It's not _only_ boundaries between whitespace and non-whitespace that `\b` can match. So this isn't really a bug that relates to escaping the `$` at all; it's a problem with using `\b` when you want behavior that doesn't match what it actually does.

Comment: ...consider replacing `\b` with a lookbehind assertion that's _specifically_ requiring either beginning-of-string or whitespace.

Comment: Ahh, that seems to have worked. The expression `((?<=[\s])|(?<=^))(?!\$)\w+` did the trick. Would you mind posting as an answer that I can use that as the accepted solution?

Comment: Feel free to do a self-answer -- you did the work of taking that hint and making it into a solution. :)

Comment: ...that said, personally, I'd use `(?<=\s|^)`; no reason to have two separate lookbehind groups when you can have just one with a fork in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to fix the pattern in the following way:

```py
\b(?<!\$)\w+
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ROZDoR).

The reason is that `\b(?!\$)\w+` is equal to `\b\w+` since `$` cannot be matched with `\w`, so no need to restrict the first char matched with `\w` with the `(?!\$)` negative lookahead. You need to restrict the char that comes *immediately before* the first char matched wit `\w`, and that is done with a *negative lookbehind*, here, `(?<!\$)`.

```py
import re
text = "$FOO FOO $BAR BAR"
print(re.findall(r"\b(?<!\$)\w+", text))
# > ['FOO', 'BAR']
```

Now, as you say `(?<=^)(?!\$)\w+|(?<=\s)(?!\$)\w+` works for you, you can now see that you may safely remove the lookaheads from the regex as they do not do anything meaningful, and the regex becomes `(?<=^)\w+|(?<=\s)\w+`. This expression can be shrunk further into a slim `(?<!\S)\w+` pattern that matches any one or more word chars that are immediately preceded with start of string or a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Charles for putting me on the right track. I had an incorrect understanding of how boundary characters function.

```
import re
text = "FOO $FOO FOO $BAR BAR"


re.findall('(?<=^)(?!\$)\w+|(?<=\s)(?!\$)\w+', text)
> ['FOO', 'FOO', 'BAR']
```

Replacing `\b` with a negative look-behind that matched a space or the beginning of a string gives the desired output.

Comment: Note that your `(?<=^)(?!\$)\w+|(?<=\s)(?!\$)\w+` = `(?<=^)\w+|(?<=\s)\w+` = `(?<!\S)\w+`. I added the description of this pattern to my answer.